# Object-oriented student library

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, python-3.x

This library management program can do following functions:

- Add a book to the library
- Display all available books
- Lend books to students
- Return books to the library
- Display students who have yet to return a book

Question: How do you *refactor* this code so that it follows OOP, reads better, is manageable and is pythonic? How can I write name functions and classes better? How do you know which data structure you need to use so as to manage data effectively?

`Library` class that *contains* a *list* of books

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self._books = []

    def add_book(self, new_book):
        self._books.append(new_book)

    def display_books(self):
        if self._books:  # if list of books is not empty
            print("The books we have made available in our library are:\n")
            for book in self._books:
                print(book)
        else:
            print("Sorry, we have no books available in the library at the moment")

    def lend_book(self, requested_book):
        if requested_book in self._books:
            print("You have now borrowed \"%s\" " % requested_book)
            self._books.remove(requested_book)

        else:
            print("Sorry, \"%s\" is not there in our library at the moment" % requested_book)
```

`StudentDatabase` class (container for all students)

```
class StudentDatabase:
    def __init__(self):
        self._books = {}

    def get_student(self, name):
        if name not in self._books:
            return "Not Found"

        return self._books[name]

    def borrow_book(self, name, book):
        if name not in self._books:
            self._books[name] = list(book)
        else:
            self._books[name].append(book)

    def return_book(self, name, book):
        if book not in self._books[name]:
            print("You don't seem to have borrowed \"%s\"" % book)
        else:
            self._books[name].remove(book)

    def display_students_with_books(self):
        for name, books in self._books.items():
            if books:
                print("%s: %s" % (name, books))
```

Follow-up : [Object-oriented student library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/207303)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the below, I recommend reading [Maarten Fabré's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/206995/140921).

---

## Edge case

Consider the following scenario:

```
book_tracking = StudentDatabase()
book_tracking.return_book("Student A", "Moby Dick")
# KeyError: 'Student A'
```

However, we don't need to do a try-except block to catch the student who never handled books before trying to return a book; Python provides [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in the collections module to help us with this very problem:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class StudentDatabase:
    def __init__(self):
        self._books = defaultdict(list)

    # ...
```

Now, if anything tries to access an unassigned key of `_books`, it will simply return an empty list. This can subsequently simplify `borrow_book()`:

```
    def borrow_book(self, name, book):
        self._books[name].append(book)
```

## Interclass operability

`Library` and `StudentDatabase` don't seem to interact at all. If they're related, the student database listing book borrows should inform the library when a book is borrowed or returned. The most versatile way to do this at this stage is to add a `library` parameter to relevant methods.

```
class StudentDatabase:
    # ...

    def borrow_book(self, name, book, library):
        if library.lend_book(book):
            self._books[name].append(book)

    def return_book(self, name, book, library):
        if book not in self._books[name]:
            print("You don't seem to have borrowed \"%s\"" % book)
        else:
            library.add_book(book)
            self._books[name].remove(book)
```

This will require returning False when the book is not found:

```
class Library:

    # ...

    def lend_book(self, requested_book):
        if requested_book in self._books:
            print("You have now borrowed \"%s\" " % requested_book)
            self._books.remove(requested_book)
            return True

        else:
            print("Sorry, \"%s\" is not there in our library at the moment" % requested_book)
            return False
```

The implementation you currently have is very simple, so there's not much else to discuss in terms of design: it becomes more relevant when you have more moving parts. I do find it somewhat odd that it's only tracking by student, and not by book (i.e. `Library` could know how many copies of each book it had (int), to whom it's checked (a list perhaps with a custom `CheckedOut` class to store the person and the due date), and any other information pertaining to that book. A `BookStatus` class could store everything related to each book; the library would then contain a list of BookStatus objects.

## Checking if a sequence is empty.

*(Note I previously advocated using `len(self._books) > 0` until Maarten Fabré (along with three people upvoting his comment) pointed out this suggestion contradicted [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)) The relevant passage is excerpted below.*

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false.

## Format string literals

You seem to be using [printf-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). In Python 3, [format strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) are more flexible and would probably be considered more Pythonic. Python 3.6 adds [format string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), which are very compact. Here are some example uses:

- Original: `"You have now borrowed \"%s\" " % requested_book`

  - With f-string: `f"You have now borrowed \"{requested_book}\"."`
- Original: `"Sorry, \"%s\" is not there in our library at the moment" % requested_book`

  - With f-string: `f"Sorry, \"{requested_book}\" is not there in our library at the moment"`
- Original: `"You don't seem to have borrowed \"%s\"" % book`

  - With f-string: `f"You don't seem to have borrowed \"{book}\""`
- Original: `"%s: %s" % (name, books)`

  - With f-string: `f"{name}: {books}"`

## Result

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self._books = []

    def add_book(self, new_book):
        self._books.append(new_book)

    def display_books(self):
        if len(self._books) > 0:
            print("The books we have made available in our library are:\n")
            for book in self._books:
                print(book)
        else:
            print("Sorry, we have no books available in the library at the moment")

    def lend_book(self, requested_book):
        if requested_book in self._books:
            print(f"You have now borrowed \"{requested_book}\".")
            self._books.remove(requested_book)
            return True

        else:
            print(f"Sorry, \"{requested_book}\" is not there in our library at the moment")
            return False

class StudentDatabase:
    def __init__(self):
        self._books = defaultdict(list)

    def get_student(self, name):
        if name not in self._books:
            return "Not Found"

        return self._books[name]

    def borrow_book(self, name, book, library):
        if library.lend_book(book):
            self._books[name].append(book)

    def return_book(self, name, book, library):
        if book not in self._books[name]:
            print(f"You don't seem to have borrowed \"{book}\"")
        else:
            library.add_book(book)
            self._books[name].remove(book)

    def display_students_with_books(self):
        for name, books in self._books.items():
            if books:
                print(f"{name}: {books}")
```

Comment: What do you mean by: "I do find it somewhat odd that it's only tracking by student, and not by book (i.e. Library could know how many copies of each book it had (int))"

Comment: @GraceMathew What I meant was that in your current library design, only the student database knows what books are checked out, not the library. Normally, when I conceive of how a library works, they distinguish books being checked out from being moved to another place. The current design of the library component of the program doesn't make such a distinction: a book is only *gone* from the library. It means you can only search for book status via students, not via the books.

Answer (score 3):

## Separate the logic and data from the presentation

`return` or `yield`, don't print. This way your code can be used in other programs that might reuse this.

## set

Your `Library` and `StudentDatabase` uses `list`s to keep the books. Since the order is not important, but checking for containment and adding and removing is more important, a `set` is a more suited container than a list. This might give a problem when a student borrows more than 1 version of a book, but this can be solved by using real objects for the books instead of just strings for the titles.

## Communicate failure with exceptions

```
def get_student(self, name):
    if name not in self._books:
        return "Not Found"
    return self._books[name]
```

No you have to always check for that special value `"Not Found"`

Better would be to raise an exception, or even just let the `KeyError` bubble up to the calling code

## String literals

There are 4 ways to delimit string literals. `"`, `'`, `"""`, `'''`. If you need both `"` and `'` in the string itself, you can use one of the other ones to delimit the string. For example `f'''{name} doesn't seem to have borrowed "{book}"'''`

Together with Graham's comments, the result could be something like:

```
class StudentDataBaseException(Exception): pass
class NoStudent(StudentDataBaseException): pass
class NoBook(StudentDataBaseException): pass


class StudentDatabase:
    def __init__(self):
        self._books = defaultdict(set)

    def get_student(self, name):
        try:
            return self._books[name]
        except KeyError as exc:
            raise NoStudent(f"Student {name} not detected in Database") from exc

    def borrow_book(self, name, book, library):
        if library.lend_book(book):
            self._books[name].add(book)

    def return_book(self, name, book, library):
        if book not in self._books[name]:
            raise NoBook(f'''{name} doesn't seem to have borrowed "{book}"''')
        else:
            library.add_book(book)
            self._books[name].remove(book)

    def display_students_with_books(self):
        for name, books in self._books.items():
            if books:
                yield f"{name}: {books}" 

    def display_students_with_books(self):
        for name, books in self._books.items():
            if books:
                yield name, books
```

I added 2 versions of the `display_students_with_books` method, one yielding a `str`, the other yielding the actual name and books objects, so the user interface can take care of the formatting

## Atomic operations

If an operation takes 2 steps, for example returning a book removes the book from a student's collection and adds it to the library, and something goes wrong with the second operation, the first operation needs to be cancelled. There are a number of ways to ensure this (`try-except` blocks,...) but this might be a concern.